# Grouping 3 columns into 1 column and generating count SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, union

I have a table that includes 3 columns (myColumnX, myColumnY, myColumnZ) with same type of values.

I am trying to generate a singular column with values from all 3 columns along with count for each value in that column.

Here is sample data:

| myColumnX | myColumnY | myColumnZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| b | c | d |
| b | a | d |
| e | b | c |

**I need a new column so I can group by and generate count; the output needs to be:**

| newColumn | count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 2 |
| e | 1 |

How do I get this result? Am I using UNION ALL?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can also use union all and count for this.

Answer (score 2):

one way :

```
select newColumn , count(*) as count
from ( 
          select myColumnX as newColumn from table 
union all select myColumnY as newColumn from table 
union all select myColumnZ as newColumn from table 
) t
group by newColumn
```

Comment: there are other ways?

Comment: Thank you! It worked how I intended it to.